# jQuery Sliders only initialize one time within a jQuery popup

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a couple of jQuery slider objects.  They live in a php script which is called via $.get to populate a jQuery popup box.  The popup is triggered by a button on the main page.  The sliders initialize perfectly the first time that the jQuery popup box is called.  But if I click the button again to call the popup box a second time, the sliders don't initialize. Any idea what could cause the problem?

Here is the relevant code from the php script that populates the html for the popup box:

```
<?php
echo <<<EOD
    Fleet Persistence: <br><br><br>
    <div id="persistence-slider">Testy Test Test</div><br><br><br>
    Fleet Spread: <br>
    <div id="spread-slider"></div>
    Fleet Behavior: <br>
EOD;
?>
<script>
    sliders();
    function sliders(){
        slider = $( "#persistence-slider" );
        slider.slider();

        $("#spread-slider").slider()
        alert("slidersdone");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem.  I had mistakenly created the /div/ for the popup box two times.  This led to all kinds of weird errors, this one included.  Problem was, I think, that jQuery got confused about which one I was trying to call and initialized two boxes at different times. It's ironed out now.  Thanks for your help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the .done() method right after your $.get() call to re-apply the sliders.

```
$.get('http://yourajax.call').done(function(){
    $("#persistence-slider").slider();
    $("#spread-slider").slider()
});
```